# Updating / validating mass update rails association

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

My recipes model is as follows

```
has_many :quantities
has_many :ingredients, :through => :quantities, :uniq => true
has_many :sizes, :through => :quantities, :uniq => true
```

And the controller action im trying to refactor

```
class Admin::QuantitiesController < Admin::AdminController
  layout 'admin'

  authorize_resource :class => :controller

  def create
    recipe        = Recipe.find(params[:recipe_id])
    values      = params[:quantity][:ingredient]
    @quantities = Quantity.find(values.keys)

    @quantities_errors = {}
    @quantities.each do |quantity|
        if quantity.value != values[quantity.id.to_s]
            quantity.value = values[quantity.id.to_s]
            if quantity.valid?
                quantity.save
            else
                @quantities_errors[quantity.id] = quantity.errors.messages
            end
        end
    end

    unless @quantities_errors
        redirect_to edit_admin_recipe_path(recipe), notice: 'Ingredients was successfully added.'
    else
        redirect_to edit_admin_recipe_path(recipe), alert: @quantities_errors
    end

  end

end
```

Comment: This is confusing. You are editing a recipe, right? (`edit_admin_recipe_path`), then why are you getting the POST in `QuantitiesController#create`? It should be in `RecipesController#update` and use Rails infrastructure (mainly `accepts_nested_attributes_for`), to remove all this boilerplate.

Comment: Thanks ever so much, after your comment I found http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 and managed to get it posting to the recipe model and using accepts_nested_attributes_for. I knew the code was dodgy hence why I posted. I didn't know about accepts_nested_attributes_for before now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes:

- This is a `edit_admin_recipe` form, so you should POST to `Admin::RecipesController#update`.
- Use Rails infrastructure for the models ([accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)) to save nested data. Controllers must be kept simple and clean.